# How to optimize negative binomial properly?

Tags: r, optimization

I have some problems optimizing the negative binomial. I always get the same error. I tried to play around with positive starting values but that doesnt solve the problem

```
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

What I did:

1. I defined the log-likelihood

   ```
   sum(lgamma((theta/(sigma2 - 1)) + 1) - lgamma(outcome+1) -lgamma(theta/(sigma2 -1))  + outcome*log((sigma2-1)/sigma2) -   (theta/(sigma2 - 1)) *log(sigma2))
   ```
2. I defined the whole function as following. That seems to run:

   ```
   ll.negbin <- function(par, covariates, outcome){
   if(!all(covariates[,1] == 1))# here I add intercept{
   covariates <- as.matrix(cbind(1,covariates))}
   theta <- covariates%*%par[1:ncol(covariates)]
   gamma <- par[(ncol(covariates)+1)]
   sigma2 <- exp(gamma)+1
   out <- sum(lgamma((theta/(sigma2 - 1)) + 1) - lgamma(outcome+1) -lgamma(theta/(sigma2 -1)) + outcome*log((sigma2-1)/sigma2) -   (theta/(sigma2 - 1)) *log(sigma2))
   }
   ```
3. optimized with optim:

   ```
   opt.negbin <- optim(par = rep(0, ncol(data[,2:6]) + 1),# here you can  put your in.var. inside
   fn = ll.negbin,
   covariates = data[,2:6], # here you can put your columns of in.var.(,2:6).
   outcome = data$,         # here you can put your dependent variable
   control = list(fnscale = -1),
   hessian = T,
   method = "BFGS")
   ```

Comment: I think you will have more luck turning this to the Cross Validated community.

Comment: Can you provide the data that you are considering for the calibration?